# Need help with HashMaps?

Tags: java

I have a following scenario:

```
    public class MapTest {
    String name = "guru";
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapTest mapTest = new MapTest();
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("name", mapTest.name);

        System.out.println(mapTest.name);
        map.put("name", "raj");
        System.out.println(mapTest.name);
    }

   }
```

output is:

```
guru
guru
```

is there any way that I can get the output as

```
guru
raj
```

ie. I want the HashMap `map` and the member variable `name` to in sync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. That's not the way Java works. When you write:

```
map.put("name", mapTest.name);
```

that's putting *the current value of `mapTest.name`* into the map. After the argument has been evaluated, it's *completely independent* of the original expression.

If you need to do something *like* this, you would have some sort of mutable wrapper class - you'd put a reference to the *wrapper* into the map, and then you can change the value within the wrapper, and it doesn't matter how you get to the wrapper, you'll still see the change.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

class StringWrapper {
    private String value;

    StringWrapper(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, StringWrapper> map = new HashMap<String, StringWrapper>();

        StringWrapper wrapper = new StringWrapper("Original");
        map.put("foo", wrapper);

        System.out.println(map.get("foo"));

        wrapper.setValue("Changed");

        System.out.println(map.get("foo"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be confused about how maps work. For a better idea, try printing out the map.

```
map.put("name", mapTest.name);
System.out.println(map);
map.put("name", "raj");
System.out.println(map);
```

You will get:

{"name"="guru"}
{"name"="raj"}

Note that mapTest.name == "guru" always as you never modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Java maps just don't support anything like this. When you do

```
    map.put("name", mapTest.name);
```

You put a reference to the object referenced by `mapTest.name` in the map. When you do

```
    map.put("name", "raj");
```

You put a reference to the new `String` object in the map. The reference to `mapTest.name` isn't in the map anymore.

Out of curiosity, why don't you want to just use `map.get("name")`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be performed dynamically, you should use a function/method.

```
public class MapTest {
    private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String name() {
        return map.get("name");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapTest mapTest = new MapTest();
        mapTest.map.put("name", "guru");
        System.out.println(mapTest.name());
        mapTest.map.put("name", "raj");
        System.out.println(mapTest.name());
    }
}
```

prints

```
guru
raj
```